# Can't open ssh connection because max socket reached

Tags: linux, sshd, socket

I've a VPS and about 100 headless device connected to VPS througth ssh inverse connection.
In the last days, the VPS reject ssh connections few minutes after reboot it with this message `kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.

If I'm connected to VPS with debug ssh flag sometimes I saw `debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1`.

I readed about it and seems the error is caused by reaching the maximum number of sockets allowed.

With `ss -xa | wc -l`:

```
494
```

But `430` are like follows and I don't know what service open this sockets:

```
Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q   Local Address:Port       Peer Address:Port
u_dgr ESTAB      0      0               * 2147483647                  * 0
```

With `cat /proc/user_beancounters`:

```
Version: 2.5
       uid  resource                     held              maxheld              barrier                limit              failcnt
   103848:  kmemsize                 66312098             68554752  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            lockedpages                     0                  503               262144               262144                    0
            privvmpages                369146               386161  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            shmpages                    74623                74943  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            numproc                       357                  393  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            physpages                  146470               154269                    0               262144                    0
            vmguarpages                     0                    0               294912  9223372036854775807                    0
            oomguarpages                99708               106874               262144  9223372036854775807                    0
            numtcpsock                    338                  339  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            numflock                       59                   64  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            numpty                          2                    4  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            numsiginfo                      0                   24  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            tcpsndbuf                 7093000              7110440  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            tcprcvbuf                 5766768              5783152  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            othersockbuf               523272               871456  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            dgramrcvbuf                     0                30520  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            numothersock                  500                  500                  500                  500                 8621
            dcachesize               26527977             26991757  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            numfile                      6064                 6290  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            numiptent                      30                   30  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
```

How can I know what service is opening so many sockets?

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of `/proc/user_beancounters` tells me this is a virtualized instance running on an OpenVZ host.  The limits of which would be at the discretion of your provider.

The counter that is failing is `numothersock` which is defined as "Maximum number of non-TCP sockets (local sockets, UDP and other types of sockets)."

Examine the output of `ss -xa` (all unix sockets) and `ss -ua` (all UDP sockets).  I have found the "Local Address:Port" column to be useful to find which processes are holding those sockets.

You would then look at the output from `lsof` and dig out process names and numbers using the port found above:

```
lsof | grep $PORT
```

That should give you some indication of what process is holding those sockets.

Comment: The `ss -xa` command output show me at 85% lines like this: `u_str ESTAB      0      0                                                           * 2147483647                                                      * 0`. The other 15% lines returned are like: `u_str LISTEN     0      0                               /path_to_different_service.2438 2147483647                                                      * 0`. How can I know to which process they belong? @GracefulRestart

Comment: `ESTAB` would mean that is an active connection, `LISTEN` would be a socket ready for connections.  You would now look through `lsof` to match the local port number to get the service.  This is working on my machine:  `for port in $(ss -xa | awk '{print $6}'); do lsof|grep $port; done`.  The first column in the output should be the service name that owns the socket.